# Why can't I send a GET request to google.com?

Tags: javascript, jquery, get

When sending a GET request to a server why is www.codecademy.com working as the url but not other url's such as www.google.com?

I have a button on my page that when I press sends a get request. The code below works, but why can't I just substitute it for any other url and get some data back? Just want to work on sending GET requests and parsing the data.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $.get("http://www.codecademy.com/",function(data,status){
      alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Short answer, before I go to bed: Cross domain requests are forbidden, but Codecademy may allow it with appropriate CORS headers.

Comment: Ok, so where can I go to practice sending get requests to a server and parsing data?

Answer (score 4):

Check the error returned:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.google.com/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '' is therefore not allowed access

In a nutshell, this is to do with CORS

This SO post may help
[Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143093/origin-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin)

... by 'help' - I mean help to understand, not help to GET request google from client side Javascript.

You could of course charm the '[Security Princess](https://plus.google.com/+ParisaTabriz/about)' of google into opening it up for you, but I highly doubt that's an option ;-)

Comment: Gotcha. Alex, where can I go to practice sending get requests to a server and parsing through data?

Comment: Google has a lot of APIs like [Youtube](https://developers.google.com/youtube/), [Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/), which use json you can parse and play with.

Comment: ... sorry, requestb.in also has same issue - I would knock up a simple node server and run it on localhost?